# How to get Google Maps API KEY from AndroidManifest.xml/AppDelegate in Flutter

Tags: flutter

Consider a Flutter application that uses both [google_maps_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter) and [google_maps_webservice](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_webservice) libraries.

- `google_maps_flutter` provides [instructions](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter#getting-started) for configuring the API KEY.  Basically, add it to the `AndroidManifest.xml` (Android) and `AppDelegate` (iOS).
- `google_maps_webservice` provides [guidance](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_webservice#usage) for configuring the API KEY.  Basically, pass it to a constructor.

Is there a way to extract the API KEY from `AndroidManifest.xml`/`AppDelegate` so that it can be passed to `google_maps_webservice`?

Answer (score 0):

You could use plugin such as [android_metadata](https://pub.dev/packages/android_metadata) to retrieve the metadata from AndroidManifest.

```dart
import 'package:android_metadata/android_metadata.dart';

Map<String, String> metadata = Map();

final metadata = await AndroidMetadata.metaDataAsMap;
final apiKey = metadata['com.google.android.geo.API_KEY'];
```

Please bear in mind that the reason why `google_maps_webservice` requires an API key passed to constructor is because it relays on web API key which is different than the platfrom API key

Comment: This appears to be an Android only solution and will not work with iOS.